# How to enable Pylint in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, lint, pylint

I can't get pylint errors to show up in VSCode. I installed pylint globally (sudo apt install pylint), I created venv and installed it there with pip, I selected pylint as linter in VSCode, enabled it, ran it, and it doesnt show any errors in my file. If I check from the command line, it shows many errors in my file.

This was working earlier, but not now on VSCode version 1.46.1 and 1.45.1 installed using snap.

Same results with the Microsoft and the Jedi python language server.

I found the pylint command in the developer console:

```
~/Documents/work/python/.venv/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.6.89148/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pylint --disable=all --enable=F,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,unused-wildcard-import,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode,E0001,E0011,E0012,E0100,E0101,E0102,E0103,E0104,E0105,E0107,E0108,E0110,E0111,E0112,E0113,E0114,E0115,E0116,E0117,E0118,E0202,E0203,E0211,E0213,E0236,E0237,E0238,E0239,E0240,E0241,E0301,E0302,E0303,E0401,E0402,E0601,E0602,E0603,E0604,E0611,E0632,E0633,E0701,E0702,E0703,E0704,E0710,E0711,E0712,E1003,E1101,E1102,E1111,E1120,E1121,E1123,E1124,E1125,E1126,E1127,E1128,E1129,E1130,E1131,E1132,E1133,E1134,E1135,E1136,E1137,E1138,E1139,E1200,E1201,E1205,E1206,E1300,E1301,E1302,E1303,E1304,E1305,E1306,E1310,E1700,E1701 --msg-template='{line},{column},{category},{symbol}:{msg}' --reports=n --output-format=text ~/Documents/work/python/micro.py
```

So pylint is indeed executed! If I run it like this from the command line, the output is:

```
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

But if I execute `pylint micro.py` I get:

```
Your code has been rated at -2.50/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, -12.50)
```

Why is VSCode using that command line? I am testing now without a .pylintrc, but even when I had it, VSCode showed no errors, only the command line! However I just tried it again, **added a .pylintrc and now the errors do show up in the editor for some reason!**

But this is only with the Jedi server, when trying with the Microsoft server, linting cannot be enabled with its command, nothing happens and it stays off.

My .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile",
        "${workspaceFolder}/backend/.pylintrc"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do `ctrl+shift+p` i guess `cmd+shift+p` on Mac and then write `select linter`. It should display you a list of the linter installed, if `pylint` is not installed you can do it with pip `pip install pylint` or conda `conda install -c anaconda pylint`

Comment: I used the commands already: select linter, enable linter, run linter, and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked your settings like the `ctrl+shift+p` settings both (json) and (ui) and see there if everything is configured normally

Comment: you can try to add `"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true` in your `settings.json` file

Comment: Yes I have that in settings.json, and "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,

Comment: So have you tried my method?

Comment: Please share your settings for VS Code related to Pylint.

Comment: It seems pylint is not executed and no error is reported when pylintrc is not found, for example due to wrong --rcfile path.

Comment: This might've been a configuration issue or bug. Right now using Pylance language server Pylint works fine.

Answer (score 27):

Simplest way using UI:

1. *Press* "**Ctrl + Shift + P**" *to get Command Palette*
2. *Type* "**Lint**"

[image]

3. *Select* "**Python : Enable/Disable Linting**", *click on "Enable"*
4. *Repeat Step 1 & 2,  now select* "**Python : Select Linter**", *Select **pylint** from options*

[image]

5. *Above steps will add below lines in* "**settings.json**" *under .vscode dir*

[image]

Comment: I dont have the `Lint` option, nor `Python: Select Linter` as it says [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) any idea why?

Comment: Make sure you have python extension installed in VS Code.

Link : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: Also check at the right bottom of VS code if the right python interpreter version is selected (in case if you have multiple versions installed)

Comment: If you're not seeing the linting lines in the settings.json, recall VS-Code has several settings (User, Remote, Workspace).  So make sure you're looking at the correct settings.json (i.e. either User, Remote, or Workspace).

Comment: I also don't have `Lint` option available in the command Pallete.

Comment: I dont have option 3

Answer (score 10):

As of March 2022, VS Code team developed a new Pylint extension. You can directly install and use it.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint

Answer (score 7):

As this post suggests, this is currently fixed: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12285#issuecomment-649350148

My .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.languageServer": "Microsoft"
}
```

It should work both on Jedi and Microsoft servers.
Cheers!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Migration-to-Python-Tools-Extensions

Comment: Those settings are deprecated now, all settings started with `python.linting` are now deprecated. see here for more info https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

Answer (score 3):

I just installed [Pylint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint) to [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as shown below. *I use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) on Windows 11:

[image]

Then, it works properly as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The linting setting has been [deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Migration-to-Python-Tools-Extensions) and now, you have to install those helper extensions (autopep8, black, pylance, flake8 and the likes) individually.
Before now you would have something like in the settings,

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
}
```

or the **Python : Enable/Disable Linting** option in the Command Panel but this is no more available. To use Pylance, add the following setting to your **settings.json**:

`"python.languageServer": "Pylance",`

If you don't want to use the settings.json,

- select the Settings UI in the Command Panel:
   `Ctrl+Shift+P > Preferences: Open Settings UI`
- search for Pylance in the search bar and
- under the *Extensions*, click on *Python* and set the Language Server
  to Pylance.

*Note that you have to have installed the Python and Pylance extension.*

Comment: How do you choose which linting extension should do the listing if you have several ones installed ?

Comment: Different linting extensions might have different settings (_irdk_) but for Pylance, it is by setting the `"python.languageServer"` setting. Check the details of whatever extension you use for the configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but resolved it after installing the [cornflakes-linter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinglasson.cornflakes-linter) for VS code.

Comment: it's a different linter, though

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps one possible solution could be launching the VS Code from the `terminal`/`cmd`.

These are the steps to enable you to launch the VS Code from the terminal (macOS), from the [VS code site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20run%20VS,code'%20command%20in%20PATH%20command.).

For installation:

1. Download Visual Studio Code for macOS.
2. Open the browser's download list and locate the downloaded archive.
3. Select the 'magnifying glass' icon to open the archive in Finder.
4. Drag Visual Studio Code.app to the Applications folder, making it available in the macOS Launchpad.
5. Add VS Code to your Dock by right-clicking on the icon to bring up the context menu and choosing Options, Keep in Dock.

Launching from the command line:

1. Launch VS Code.
2. Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type `shell command` to find the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` command.
3. Restart the terminal for the new `$PATH` value to take effect. You'll be able to type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

Launching the VS Code from the command line in `venv`:

1. Activating `venv` in your terminal/command line, for my case, I use `source activate venv`
2. Launch VS Code after the activation of `venv`, using `code .` in the desired directory.

For [Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows) and [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux), the steps to set up the path can be found in the links.

Comment: No this does not make any difference.