# Install pip3 and flake8 in conda venv on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pip, ubuntu-20.04, python-venv, flake8

Goal: get flake8 linting working

I setup a new conda venv. I try to select Flake8 as my linter in Command Palette.

Update: I've installed `pip` and `flake8`. However, VS Code prompts:

- `Linter flake8 is not installed`
- `There is no pip installer in the selected environment`

Ubuntu Bash Terminal:

```sh
(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 124 not upgraded.

(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ pip install flake8
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes<2.5.0,>=2.4.0 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flake8) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.9.0,>=2.8.0 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flake8) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flake8) (0.6.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true
}
```

---

I've been following along to these solutions with no luck

[Install Pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900714/there-is-no-pip-installer-available-in-the-selected-environment)

[Use Flake8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473201/how-do-i-enable-pylint-in-vscode)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code | Linter flake8 is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157192/vs-code-linter-flake8-is-not-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a conda environment properly:

```
conda create -n "myenv" python
```

then, activate the environment:

```
conda activate myenv
```

finally, install flake:

```
pip install flake8
```

Comment: I did: `conda create -n "sdg2" python=3.8.8`, `conda activate sdg2`, `pip install flake8`. Then followed steps to setup flake8, but still get `Linter flake8 is not installed` ;(

Comment: When I click `Install` on that prompt, I immediately get `There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment.` prompt

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 Sounds like vscode isn't picking up flake. Have you tried enabling it in settings.json?

Comment: `settings.json` added to post

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 have you tried reloading vscode? Ctrl+shift+p then reload

Comment: I'll fully exit and go back into VS Code and its Terminal

Comment: `Updating Visual Studio Code...`

Comment: Let's keep our comments here ^^ for future reference. Thank you :)